# Static text element between two md-input-containers

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material and have a couple of select inputs on a form that I would like to separate with a piece of static text.

Both the selects are in md-input-containers and so the text that sits between the two needs to have the same padding around as so I have had to use a further input container to hold the static text like so:

```
<div layout="row" flex layout-padding>
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label translate>Select 1</label>
        <md-select ng-model="option1" flex>
            <md-option ng-repeat="option in options">
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
        <label></label>
        <input type="text" value="label" readonly>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label translate>Select 2</label>
        <md-select ng-model="option2" flex>
            <md-option ng-repeat="option in options">
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](http://codepen.io/parky128/pen/rLWJNK)

It feels a bit hacky, and I wondered if anyone had any better suggestions.

I dont want the text to have any border bottom on, I know I could just roll my own css, but I wondered if there was a way out of the box using the AM framework?

Comment: Using a table perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple. Just use `span` element with `layout-align` attribute on parent element.

Here is the code

```
<div layout="row" flex layout-padding layout-align="start center">
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label translate>Select 1</label>
    <md-select ng-model="option1" flex>
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in options">
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <span flex>Label</span>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label translate>Select 2</label>
    <md-select ng-model="option2" flex>
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in options">
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Here is working Example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/PzbXpv

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be a way using the built in layout attributes. Thanks :)